# Lua sending a called function's name

Tags: lua, agen-framework

Basically I want to know when function;

```
button[n]:onclick() --where n can be any string value
```

gets called, and send its name (specifically I want to send "n") to another function;

```
function allbuttons(n) --where n is the n from button[n]:onclick()
```

which then processes all possible requests.
I want to do this because button[n] is specified, and therefore the button[n]:onclick() gets triggered every time the button is clicked, but it doesn't seem right to write these function every time I want another buttonclick to be processed in the big allbuttons function;

```
function button['options']:onclick()
  allbuttons('options')
end
function button['quit']:onclick()
  allbuttons('quit')
end

(...)

function button[n]:onclick()
  allbuttons(n)
end
```

I've tried something like;

```
debug.sethook(allbuttons, 'c')
function allbuttons()
  n = debug.getinfo(2).name
end
```

but I guess I don't fully understand how to use debug.sethook ..

Comment: No it's AGen (http://www.2dengine.com)

Comment: you can not do that but you can do `function define_onclick(b,n) b[n].onclick=function()allbuttons(n)end end
define_onclick(button, 'options')
define_onclick(button, 'quit')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `button[n]:onclick` to be the function you want (allbuttons), except that here there is one tricky bit, the value n. You likely know already that you could do

```
button[n].onclick = allbuttons
```

But if the event dispatcher calls `onclick` as `button[n]:onclick()` then `allbuttons` will always get button as first argument. If what you really want in `allbuttons` is to know the `button[n]` instance that was clicked, all you need to do is change the definition of `allbuttons(n)` to `allbuttons(button)` and change its code accordingly.

If you need n and it's not available any other way, you can create an anonymous closure with access to n as an upvalue (see http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html for details):

```
function sendClickToCommon(button, n)
    button[n].onclick = function (self) 
                            allbuttons(n)
                        end
end
sendClickToCommon(button, 1)
sendClickToCommon(button, 2)
sendClickToCommon(button, 3)
```

Or you could do it this way too:

```
function getAllbuttonsN(n)
    return function (self) 
               allbuttons(n)
           end
end
button[1].onclick = getAllbuttonsN(1)
```

The code is simpler but the index appears twice in the expression, a potential source of error.

Comment: `button[n]:onclick =` is no valid. you need `button[n].onclick =`

Comment: The second alternative worked for me, and I now use button[n].onclick = function() allbuttons(n) end, which appears to do the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Alistaire you mean `button[1].onclick = function() allbuttons(1) end`, and so forth? Sure that will work too. But then you are duplicating a pile of code. Unless n is available as an upvalue, for example in a function you call for each field in button table (which is actually equivalent to the first technique).

Comment: I'm indeed looping through a button table.